# referencing multiple foreign keys php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, new-operator, foreign-key-relationship

I'm very new to php/MySQL and I'm having a bit of trouble.  Help would be much appreciated.

I have 2 tables laid out as such:

**table team**

team_id,team_name

**table schedule**

game_id,game_time,team1_id,team2_id,location

schedule.team1_id and schedule.team2_id are both foreign keys to team.team_id.

I'm trying to reference team_name using team1_id and team2_id but I can only ever seem to get the name for team1.  This is the query I've used unsuccessfully.

```
SELECT * FROM team
AS t JOIN schedule AS s 
ON t.team_id = s.team1_id 
WHERE location='1';
```

My attempt to output the data:

```
while (mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['team_name'];
}
```

It's quite obvious to me why this isn't working, as the tables are joined on only one of the columns I need.  Help!  I'm completely lost as to how to solve this problem.  I believe there is a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear on what you would like the results of your query to look like, but I am assuming you would like to get information about both teams involved in each game. To do so, you'll have to join the `team` table twice:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name, s.* 
FROM schedule AS s 
INNER JOIN team AS t1 ON t1.team_id = s.team1_id 
INNER JOIN team AS t2 ON t2.team_id = s.team2_id 
WHERE s.location='1';
```

Comment: thank you so much matt! the tables are successfully joined, and the sql result returns 'team_name','team_name', etc etc...  My next question is.. How would I output them in a table?  I don't quite understand how to output the 1st team_name and the 2nd team_name, as they are both named 'team_name' in the array that mysql_fetch_assoc($result) returns.

Comment: you can use aliases in the `select` clause as well as in the `from` clause, such as `select t1.name AS t1name, t2.name as t2name` etc