# PHP nested loops with foreign key table

Tags: php, database-design, foreign-keys, nested-loops

This is a multi-part question. My database looks like this:

```
USERS
-id
-fname
-lname

COMPANIES
-id
-name
-type

PRODUCTS
-id
-product
-restaurant (foreign key to companies id)
-vendor (foreign key to companies id)
-user (foreign key to users id)
-transaction_date
```

1. Is this a good way to set up the database? I was thinking of having separate tables for restaurants and vendors but wanted them to use the same login page and rather than have to worry about UNION queries, I just select them by type. They see different information upon login so I have an if statement that says if type = r, show this else show that. Best way?

The second issue comes up when I want to show the information upon login. Say a vendor logs in, they will see a list of all the records that match their vendor id. However, I am seeing too many records because of my nested loop. For example, the table looks like this:

```
Date--Product--Restaurant--User
```

I am using this query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT products.*, companies.name, CONCAT_WS(' ', users.fname, users.lname) AS fullname FROM products INNER JOIN companies ON products.vendor = companies.id INNER JOIN users ON products.user = users.id WHERE company='$id' AND companies.type='$type'") or die(mysql_error());

$num=mysql_num_rows($sql);

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT products.restaurant, companies.name AS cname FROM products INNER JOIN companies ON products.restaurant = companies.id") or die(mysql_error());

$num1=mysql_num_rows($sql1);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
  $j = 0;
  while ($j < $num) {
$d = mysql_result($sql,$i,"transaction_date");
$p = mysql_result($sql,$i,"product");
$r = mysql_result($sql1,$j,"cname");
$u = mysql_result($sql,$i,"fullname");

<td><?php echo $d; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $p; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $r; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $u; ?></td>

$j++; }
$i++; }
```

`$id` and `$type` are session created values upon login. There are 4 example records currently in the table. Rather than showing just 4, it shows 16 because the values of `$num` and `$num1` are both 4 and `$num` is looping `$num1` four times.

1. How can I fix this problem and just show the 4 records?

Thank you for your help. Let me know if you need any clarification on any part.

Comment: does each product have one and only one user? if so your schema looks fine. if not, you'll want to make a product_users table containing the product_id, user_id, and transaction date.

Comment: Yes each product has only one user. Actually I should rename the Products table to Transactions because there is essentially only one product.

Answer (score 1):

Your database set-up may need a little rethink.

The reason I think this is that you need to know which company each user is in and you cannot have this within the products table as you have.

I would consider adding the foreign key to the **users** table like so (assuming one user has one company and one company has many users). I have also made some other suggestions, something like the below:

**users**
 - id
 - company_id
 - first_name 
 - last_name

**companies**
 - id
 - name
 - company_type_id

**company_types**
 - id
 - type

**products**
 - id
 - product_name
 - company_id

**transactions**
 - id
 - user_id
 - product_id
 - transaction_date

`they will see a list of all the records that match their vendor`

Now you will notice I removed the vendor id from the above tables - This is because the vendor id is the same as the company id. There is no point having two separate relationship id's for the same thing (correct me if I'm mistaken)

So with the above changes we can list these records easily, as so:

```
<?php

  $db   = new PDO(/**Connection info here**/);
  $stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
      a.id AS product_id,
      a.product_name
    FROM 
      products AS a
    INNER JOIN
      companies AS b ON b.id = a.company_id
    INNER JOIN
      company_types AS c ON c.id = b.type_id
    WHERE
      b.id = :company AND c.id = :companyType
  ");
  $stmt->bindParam(":company", $usersCompanyIdHere, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(":companyType", $usersCompanyTypeHere, PDO::PARAM_INT);

  $data = $stmt->execute();

  while ($row = $data->fetch()) {
    /** List of all the products for given company id**/
  }

?>
```

I have changed you code to use PDO, I don't want to overload you with info here but I **cannot stress enough** the benefits of using the **PDO** over native `mysql_*` functions - Do a Google search, I can see lots of useful and relevant information in the top 10 results.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You provided a great detailed answer but I may have not explained the design correctly. There are customers, vendors and restaurants. There is essentially only one product so I should rename the `Products` table to `Transactions`. Each record in the `Transactions` table will include a date, a user, a restaurant and a vendor. When a vendor logs in, they will only see the records that includes them showing them the date, user, restaurant. When a restaurant logs in, they will see the records that include them showing them the date, user, vendor.

Comment: I put the vendors and restaurants under the same table of `Companies` because I did not want to do UNION queries of two tables. Can I query a table to show me that data I'm requesting the way it is set up? If so how? Thank you.

Comment: I looked at PDO and will implement that also. Do you know if my database design works? Or should I change it so the loop can work?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly vendors are? are they the owners of the restaurants? What you should think about here is that **anyone** who "logs in" is a user, it just so happens that each user has a different relationship to the products/restaurants/vendors etc

Comment: There are customers (currently users table), restaurants, products (maybe should change this to transactions as there is only one product) and there are vendors. What will occur is that when a transaction occurs, a row in the Products table will be generated listing the date, Product A, the customer id who generated it, the restaurant id it took place at and the vendor id tied to that restaurant. There are certain vendors tied to certain restaurants. Hope that helps.

Comment: I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254301/referencing-multiple-foreign-keys-php-mysql

which is basically what I'm looking for but I could not get it to work.